# C++ для чего делают вложенные неймспесы внутри безымянного неймспейса

Tags: c++, системное-программирование

Для чего в коде на C++ определения заворачивают в двойные неймспейсы вот например:

```
namespace
{
    namespace vga
    {
        struct Cell
        {
            char symbol;
            unsigned char color;
        };

        static_assert(sizeof(Cell) == sizeof(unsigned short));

        static constexpr unsigned int addr = 0xB8000;

        static constexpr unsigned char width = 80;
        static constexpr unsigned char height = 25;

        using Screen = Cell[height][width];

        Screen& screen() noexcept
        {
            return *reinterpret_cast<Screen *>(addr);
        }
    }
}
```

Реализация записи символов в видеобуфер по адресу `0xB8000`. Для чего namespace vga положен в безымянный неймспейс? Это как-то упрощает программу, а не усложняет? Для чего это?

Comment: @AlexF Там скорее зачем нужны безымянные неймспейсы, а тут — какой смысл во вложенном неймспейсе? По сути: мне просто кажется, что это как лишнее самодокументирующее пояснение, к чему относится данный код.

Comment: Это ведь не в хедере? В .cpp?

Comment: Хорошо бы указать, откуда взят этот код, чтобы прояснить контекст.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/729144/) хорошая статья, которая описывает не только безымянные неймспейсы, но и затрагивает темы, которые необходимы для их понимания. Прочитайте, может станет понятнее что такое анонимный неймспейс и с чем его едят